# Get the absolute static file URL in my Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

**I want to know how can I get the absolute URL of my static file directly in my template in Django ?**

For now in my template :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}">
```

return

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

How can I get on dev:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

on production

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mycompany.com/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Why? This will make your code less portable and prone to errors. Is there an issue that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I need absolute URL for my favicon and IE 7/8 and HTML4 compatibility. I hope there was a simplier solution than site framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options:

1. recommended: use the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) to render the appropriate domain
2. *not* recommended: store your current domain as a Django setting in the settings file you use depending on your environment

I usually go for (1), the only downside being that you have to update the current domain in the DB, but that usually happens *just once* per deployment.

Then the appropriate domain will be displayed irrelevant of where code is running; you should always use the `static` tag in your template, rather than handling the display of the domain manually.